# Does 0 % 2 == 0?

Tags: python

In Python, Is 0 % 2 == 0? I would think so, but the below question says not:

> Question 14 [3.75 marks]
>   Consider the following block of Python code:
>
> ```
> if num <= 0: 
>     print('A') 
> if num >= 10: 
>     print('B') 
> if num % 2 == 0: 
>     print('C')
> ```
>
> Which of the following values for num would each cause 'C' (and no other letter) to be printed?
>
> (a)  When `num` is 2, 4, 6, or 8 # (a) is the answer
>   (b)  When `num` is 2, 4, 6, 8 or 10
>   (c)  When `num` is 0, 2, 4, 6 or 8
>   (d)  When `num` is 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 or 10
>   (e)  When `num` is 0, 4, 6, 8, or 10

Comment: seemed should use `elif` rather than `if` ?

Comment: @fish_ball Well the question says (and no other letter); if `elif` were used the way I think you're thinking then at most 1 letter could have appeared.  I think the question intended on three `if`s so that more than one letter could be printed potentially.

Comment: Have you tried running the code with `num` equal to any of those values — or even just set to 0 — to see what output you get?

Comment: @fish_ball: no, the question is quite correct; it is the OP that misunderstood here.

Comment: `and no other letter` matters, which I missed at the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short explanation**

> (and no other letter)

0 is less than or equal to 0 so A will be printed.

**Longer explanation** *(in case the short one was unclear to you)*

There are three conditions being checked:

A. `num <= 0`

B. `num >= 10`

C. `num % 2 == 0` (i.e. `num` is an even integer in plain English)

If you run `0` through those three conditions you'll see that it meets the criteria for both A. and C., so both A. and C. would be printed.

The question wants numbers that cause C. (**and not A. or B.**) to be printed.  Therefore any set containing `0` would not satisfy the question, even though, yes, `0` is an even integer.

Answer (score 4):

When `num = 0`, the first `if` is true and `A` is printed. It doesn't matter that `0 % 2 == 0` (it is) because the question asks if **just** `C` is printed:

> 'C' **(and no other letter)**

For this to be true, any answer that includes numbers that are 0 or lower, or 10 or higher can be eliminated. Only `(a)` fits that criteria.